# Python Version 2.7.6. psutil version 2.1.3 - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'users'

Tags: python-2.7, psutil

I am running UBUNTU 14.04. Python version is 2.7.6 and psutil version is 2.1.3

I import psutil and then call one of the following only to get errors.

```
    import psutil
    psutil.users()
    psutil.pids()
    psutil.cpu_times()
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'users'

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pids'

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'boot_time'

I **do not** have this issue with psutil.cpu_percent() and psutil.cpu_times()

Answer (score 0):

Try to print `psutil.__version__`. It's likely you're using an old version (< 2.X).